# Finding sum of primes below 2000000

Tags: java, integer-overflow

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 2;
    int isPrime;
    for(int x = 3; x < 2000000; x+=2){
        isPrime = 0;
        int y = 3;
        while(isPrime == 0) {
            if(x % y==0){
                isPrime = 1;
            }
            if(y > Math.ceil(x/2)) {
                isPrime = 1;
                sum+=x;
            }
            y += 2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

The code above works for x < 1000, but I am getting the wrong answer for x = 2000000 and I am having trouble understanding why.

Comment: What does "breaks down" mean?

Comment: Does the code produce an error ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of something called [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). Briefly, it refers to the concept that integers in computer have a maximum number of bits (i.e. digits in binary). `int` has a maximum of 32-bits, meaning that the largest number possible is `2^32-1` in an unsigned system. And if you add 1 to that number you get `0`, because there are no more digits to carry the 1!

So for your code use `long` (which has a 64-bit limit):

```
long sum = 2;
for(int i = 3 ; i < 2000000 ; i+=2) if(/*i is Prime*/) sum += i;
System.out.println(sum);
```

Here's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WN8i5cwjkSE) that explains what it is.

Comment: It is not an overflow `2^32-1` is `4294967295` that i think is sufficient for this problem.

Comment: @uSeemSurprised it's not sufficient, I tested it. The answer is `142913828922` which is way past the limit

Comment: yes, you are right. I ran the code did not notice the overflow.

Comment: BTW Java doesn't have an `unsigned int`

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know... but he doesn't know about overflow.. I didn't want to overwhelm him with an unnecessary complication which adds nothing to the explanation.

Comment: @Maljam You don't consider introducing a type which doesn't exist in Java an "unnecessary complication"  I +1 btw.

Comment: @PeterLawrey l thought it would be less confusing this way.. thanks for 1+, appreciated

Comment: @Maljam I see you point, though this assumes that the OP finds it easier to understand based on previous knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

`int` in Java is a **signed** number where the largest possible value is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1. As your largest value is around 2 million you would only need just over 1000 values of this size for the sum to exceed the ~ 2 billion limit. When this limit is exceed, the `int` type keeps the lowest 32-bits, rather than throwing an error, which can look like a sane result, but is actually incorrect.

BTW You can see when this happens by replacing

```
sum+=x;
```

with

```
sum = Math.addExact(sum, x);
```

this check for overflows.

```
public static int addExact(int x, int y) {
    int r = x + y;
    // HD 2-12 Overflow iff both arguments have the opposite sign of the result
    if (((x ^ r) & (y ^ r)) < 0) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("integer overflow");
    }
    return r;
}
```

I suggest using a `long` which has a limit ~ 9 billion billion.

BTW If you need all the primes up to a known limit, using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is likely to be a more efficient solution. Searching all the possible factors of a number tends to be more efficient if you want to check a number at random.

---

Here is how I would write what you have to use a `long` and simplify the code.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    long sum = 2;
    for(int x = 3; x < 2000000; x += 2) 
        if (isPrime(x)) 
           sum += x;

    System.out.println(sum);
}

/**
 * @param x is the number we check for if it is a prime
 */
static boolean isPrime(long x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) 
        return false;
    for (int y = 3; y * y <= x; y += 2) 
        if (x % y == 0) 
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program has 2 problems the first as specified by @Malijam the answer would overflow.

The second is regarding the complexity it is `O(n^2)` worst case. That is way too many operations.

You can modify your code a little to make it `O(n * sqrt(n))` by checking for factors that are less than the square root of the candidate number, that would be faster.

Modified code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long sum = 2;
    long isPrime;
    for(int x = 3; x < 2000000; x+=2){//x is the number we check for if it is a prime
        isPrime = 0;
        long y = 3;
        while(isPrime == 0) {
            if(x%y==0){
                isPrime = 1;
            }
            if(y*y > x) {
                isPrime = 1;
                sum+=x;
            }
            y += 2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Demo on Ideone : http://ideone.com/k1XAuA

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to work on my computer. The code printed 1179908154, which is different from what is shown in uSeemSurprised's answer, but it should have gaven you an output. It took quite long for an arithmetic program (about 2 minutes), but it worked fine. It might just be taking a very long time depending on your computer's power.

PS: I made some changes to make the program not take as long. I turned

if(y > Math.ceil(x/2))

to

if(y*3>x)

calling Math.ceil is really inefficient when you're running the code literally millions of times. I think multiplying is also faster than dividing. I also moved the declaration of the int y outside of the for loop. The resulting code turned out to be three times as fast.

Answer (score 0):

A generalized answer:
You and find some of all the prime number till n through below code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   long long int tc,N;
    unsigned long long int sum=0;
   vector <long long int>v;
    long long int arr[1000000] = {0},i,j;
    for (i = 2; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        for ( j = i * i; j < 1000000; j+=i)
        {
            arr[j - 1] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i - 1] == 0)
            v.push_back(i);
    }
       cout<<"\nEnter the number:";
       cin>>N;
       i=1;
       while(v.at(i)<=N)
       {
           sum+=v.at(i);
           i++;
       }
       cout<<sum<<"\n";
       sum=0;

   return 0;
}
```